# Conditional .htaccess redirects to subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The logic of RewriteCond somehow continues to elude me, so maybe somebody could take a look at my current problem:

I have to sort a very (*very*) confusing page that has a quite poorly configured virtual domain system in place. The easiest way for the moment seems to be redirects in the .htaccess.

Basically, I want to express the following to mod_rewrite:

**IF** request string contains the directories /aaa or /bbb
**AND** the subdomain is not www. , **THEN** redirect the request to http://www.foo.com/ *and keep any URI-parts that might follow, like/aaa/target-dir/index.html* .

Same for /ddd: if subdomain is not sub1., redirect towards http://sub1.foo.com/ddd (as well as for 2 more subdomains).

My attempt so far was

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.foo\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /aaa/|/bbb/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.foo\.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub1\.foo\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /ddd/|/eee/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub1\.foo\.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

but that did not work for some reason.

What's my mistake? Anyone got an idea?

edit: The complete .htaccess as follows

```
##
# @package      Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2012 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license      GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.

## OSMap Adjustment
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sitemap.xml
RewriteRule .* /index.php?option=com_osmap&view=xml&tmpl=component&id=3

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sub1-sitemap.xml
RewriteRule .* /index.php?option=com_osmap&view=xml&tmpl=component&id=1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sub2-sitemap.xml
RewriteRule .* /index.php?option=com_osmap&view=xml&tmpl=component&id=2


## Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|sub1|sub2|sub3).foo.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.foo.com/$1 [R=301,L]

## RewriteEngine On
## RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
## RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]


## /aaa , /bbb => www.foo.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.foo\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /aaa/|/bbb/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.foo\.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


## /ddd, /eee => sub1.foo.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub1\.foo\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /ddd/|/eee/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub1\.foo\.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


## /fff, /ggg => sub2.foo.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub2\.foo\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /fff/|/ggg/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub2\.foo\.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I tried to access http://sub1.foo.com/aaa/test.html , @anubhava, which should redirect to www., but doesn't for some reason.

Comment: Same domain, just a virtual subdomain, as mentioned above.

Comment: Is this complete .htaccess? If not show it in question

Comment: Why do you have `{%REQUEST_URI}` instead of `%{REQUEST_URI}` ?

Comment: Hmm, that's clearly a mistake, thanks for pointing it out.
Doesn't seem to solve the problem, though.
 Corrected above.

Comment: Can you show `VirtualHost` entry of main/sub domain?